# Turn Off All Google (Gmail) Security

Tags: gmail, google-account, security, passwords

I want to turn off all gmail security and nonsense.  Like back to the days when a SECURE PASSWORD was good enough.

I travel a lot and have different cell phone plans for different countries I'm in.  However, I keep getting blocked trying to log into my gmail because it 'doesn't recognise where I'm logging in from'.  Most of the time the solution is sending a ping or text or something to one of my phones - except I don't always have it on me.

Basically I want to change the Google/gmail settings so that whenever someone enters the CORRECT PASSWORD they can get into my account.

It boggles my mind this is even an issue for a free email service in which you can have unlimited accounts and can use them for many purposes...

Comment: Simply speaking: You can't. You'll need to find another service.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't.

You don't want to disable Google's authentication safeguards - and, generally speaking, you can't (because they not only protect you; they also protect Google - as well  as the Internet ecosystem as a whole).

Even if the user doesn't care about a specific account, Google *itself* might still care - for very good and practical reasons. For example, when a spammer compromises a "throwaway" account to send spam ... a bunch of people would be spammed, which would be reported to Google as spam ... and Google would then have to investigate and clean up the mess. (And this is only one example of how giving users an option to disable these measures would have its own operational burden; there are many more.)

So I'd like to answer your more broad, implied question - how to efficiently use GMail and its security features while traveling and regularly changing devices:

1. Install Google Authenticator on an extra/fallback device that you will always have with you, even without service. It provides the second factor - even when you are offline and cannot receive texts. Once installed, the phone that holds Google Authenticator requires no service at all (but you still have to have the device with you).
2. Use a U2F key. This provides the second without having to have a complex device at all - just a sub-US$20, no-power-required USB device that fits on your keychain. This requires that you're reading your GMail on a system that has a USB port. (There are also fobs that speak NFC).
3. Print the ten backup codes provided by Google, and use them when you don't have the device that carries Google Authenticator. This is sub-optimal because you can only use them once per device/session (so it's probably not really an option, but I'm including it here for completeness)

You might also experiment with creating an app-specific password, but I don't expect this to work well for your use case (because Google's "you are coming from somewhere weird" heuristics would probably activate).

One of the first two options should fit most use cases. To maximize your chances of being able to log in, I'd actually recommend both GA and U2F.

Comment: how is requiring a phone number making anything more secure? They ask me the same thing, except I have no phone number I even have given to google, so basically anyone with a phone would look as legit as me.

Comment: @AnneAunyme I have the same problem. It's all BS designed to look like it's making things more secure. Times I've had my emails (on any service) compromised after 20 years and over 15 different email accounts? 0. Times I've been locked out of my account because I drove to the airport, tried to log in from there, flew across the country and tried to log in from there? Over a dozen. gmail's algorithm can't even figure out what travel is, and there's no way to warn the system about it. It's a pile of garbage. (All on the same device. They actively sabotage you if you use Outlook/IE.)

Comment: Sorry to hear about your trouble. If you switch to 2FA, it should reduce your lockouts (because Google then has to rely on location heuristics less). Also, as people do more online, taking over their accounts increases in value to the attacker, so 20 years is not representative of the current risk model. Further, this methodology significantly reduces account takeover (and how much work Google has to do to clean up afterwards). https://security.googleblog.com/2017/11/new-research-understanding-root-cause.html. Might it need tuning? Yes. Is it better than not having it? Definitely. (& Use 2FA!)

Comment: @RoyceWilliams what's 2FA ?

Comment: -1  it's not for you to tell him he doesn't want to, he told you he does want to

Comment: @barlop I totally get that that's the StackExchange Way. But there is a spectrum there; If someone asks me how to remove the brakes in their car, I have an ethical obligation to discourage that. And in this case, the short answer is "You can't - but there are ways to get more of what it sounds like you want." And that's what my answer is trying to achieve, and I stand by it.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams  It's not removing the breaks, he still can have a strong password.

Comment: I think folks are missing the point that people have many, many email addresses for many purposes.  I can go and make any email address I want right now and not care about the security.

For example, lets say I make an throwaway email address for a single one-time project and that project requires me to travel to various places.  What happens is that now every time I log in from a different IP I get locked out due to this enforced 'security' that I don't want or care about.

I'm not saying turn off all security checks by default - I'm saying give people the option.

Comment: You mentioned the throwaway aspect in passing at the end of your question, so I didn't realize that it was fundamental to your ask. If you want this level of flexibility, your only option is to use a different provider (Yahoo, Hotmail, etc.). But moving to them to escape comprehensive authentication heuristics is likely only a temporary reprieve. All major providers are moving this direction (and IMO for good reason). Supporting throwaway functionality is probably low on their priority list, vs protecting vulnerable users at scale whose emails control account resets for their entire lives.

Comment: "You don't want to disable Google's authentication safeguards" that may be your opinion but lots of people don't agree with you and I don't think it's your place to tell the OP what they think

Comment: For me, one of the biggest values of StackExchange is that I can find out if I'm doing something incorrectly - or that I shouldn't be doing at all. :) It would be reasonable for me to expand my answer, to explain more about *why* I have this opinion. But in my opinion ;), it's more than just my opinion; it's backed by a *ton* of public authentication research and ops info (which shows that single-factor authentication is *deeply* vulnerable). It's also driven by Google's experience as a high-value target over time. Bottom line: if my kid wants to touch fire, I have a *duty* to tell them no. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience to date, if you remove your mobile number from your google profile then it won't(/can't) ask you for a verification code if you login on a different (new) computer.

(Note we need to be clear here that two-factor authentication (2FA) is different from account verification when you use a new device that Google doesn't know about)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about relevance I had same problem with Ubuntu Gmail was fine with Thunderbird until it would (supposedly) not verify username & password. I think they dont like VPN,s..sorry well I do. In my case I opened up a new email account in thunderbird & changed settings from POP to IMAP & now its working fine